# use DOM to identify a number in sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, children

I'm pretty sure I could word the title better, but I struggled to get this into word.

I have a sequence of identical DOM elements:

```
<div class="some_element"></div>
<div class="some_element"></div>
<div class="some_element"></div>
```

is it possible, using jQuery, to establish which number in the child sequence is being worked on, so that I can work on them individually?

Comment: If you use a selector to get a list of those `div`s, you can use the index of said list to know which `div` you're working with. There's possibly a better way to do it, but that's what immediately sprang to mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.each($('div'), function(index, value) {
    // value is the current element in the iteration.
    value.text('div ' + index);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Iterate through the elements
$(".some_element").each(function(){
   // Get the index (zero-based)
   var itemIndex = $(this).index();
   // ???
   $(this).html(itemIndex);
   // Profit!
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="some_element">1</div>
<div class="some_element" id="id2">2</div>
<div class="some_element">3</div>

$('#id2').index(); // 1 since it's a zero-based index
```

If the markup were slightly more complicated:

```
<div class="some_element">1</div>
<span class="some_other_element">useless</span>
<div class="some_element" id="id2">2</div>
<div class="some_element">3</div>

$('#id2').index(); // 2 since it looks at all the siblings
$('#id2').index('.some_element'); // 1 again, that's better
```

Finally, it can get a little more complicated/customised if you have a custom jquery object:

```
$('.some_element')
.filter(function(){return Number($(this).text())<=2;}) // custom collection
.index($('#id2')); // 1
```